# How to use PHPUnit's setExpectedException()?

Tags: php, phpunit

With PHPUnit I can **successfully test** if a specific call to a class properly throws an exception like this:

```
try 
{
    $dummy = Import_Driver_Excel::get_file_type_from_file_name('BAD_NAME.nnn');   
}
catch (Exception $ex) 
{
    return;
}
$this->fail("Import_Driver_Excel::get_file_type_from_file_name() does not properly throw an exception");
```

But I read [here](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions) that there is a **simpler way**, basically in one line using `setExpectedException()`:

```
class ExceptionTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testException()
    {
        $this->setExpectedException('InvalidArgumentException');
    }
}
```

But how do I get it to work as in the above example, i.e. I want to test that the class throws this exception **only when I make the specific call with 'BAD_NAME.nnn'?** These variants don't work:

```
$dummy = Import_Driver_Excel::get_file_type_from_file_name('BAD_NAME.nnn');  
$this->setExpectedException('Exception');
```

nor this:

```
$this->setExpectedException('Exception');
$dummy = Import_Driver_Excel::get_file_type_from_file_name('BAD_NAME.nnn');
```

**How do I use setExpectedException() to replace my working example above?**

Comment: Your second example is the correct. Can you point out what's not working.

Comment: `$this->setExpectedException('Exception'); throw new Exception();` -- what if you perform this code?

Comment: It does indeed work as in the second example, thanks.

Comment: well, follow this template then: a) set expectations b) run test methods c) PROFIT!!!1 ;-)

Comment: You could use the comment annotation also. http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.expectedException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [expectedException annotation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions.examples.ExceptionTest.php):

```
class ExceptionTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function testException()
    {
        $dummy = Import_Driver_Excel::get_file_type_from_file_name('BAD_NAME.nnn');

    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, does this solve the problem? I thought OP was concerned about getting false positives from exceptions thrown by code other than the BAD_NAME call. The annotation doesn't narrow this down.